# Asymptotic analysis using master theorem

Tags: time-complexity

T(n)= T(\sqrt{n})+logn

I have problem solving this recurrence using master theorem, If i apply substitution things will get messy. Please suggest some procedure to solve this type of equation.

Comment: For people to be able to help you, please add some description on what specifically you're trying to achieve with the things that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The master theorem only works for recurrences of the shape `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)` with `a >= 1` and `b > 1`. Your example does not fit these criteria, meaning that this recurrence cannot be solved using the master theorem.

> If i apply substitution things will get messy. Please suggest some procedure to solve this type of equation.

The substitution method requires a lot of intuition. If you are unfamiliar with solving recurrences, you are unfortunately going to have a hard time with it. I would suggest using the recursion tree method. While it is quite tedious to apply, it works in all cases.